# is it possible to create an application that uses sql server DB as a standalone app?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I´m creating an application in visual studio 2008, C#, that uses a DB.
The DB is designed in SQL Server 2008.
Think of it as a simple standalone app (not a web solution) where the user can store data about her books, like height, weight, language, and so on. Well, I´m creating another kind of app, but as an example it´s ok.

Now, the question is, how do I deliver this to the user.
I don´t want the user to download a SQL Server package, I just want the user to click on the "setup.exe" and everything should work without any more downloads and installations!
Is it possible to "embed" the DB in a "software delivery" towards a user that have no SQL Server installed?

Note, **the user should have the DB / SW app on her own computer for "own use"**, not on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) was made for just that.  You can have this as part of your setup.exe and the user will never know that an RDMBS is resident.

Comment: Thanks! Should I use the SQL Server Compact Edition also when designing the DB - that is, NOT use my SQL Server 2008 at all, but only use SQL Server Compact Edition both for design and "embedded distribution"?

Comment: @JackJohnstone I believe there are inherently restrictions in CE as opposed to Express (if that's what you've used to develop), but I can not be sure what they are.  I'd develop towards Compact Edition if you plan to use it for production.  If you already have a database design, try to migrate it and see if it is successful.  I'm not sure of the compatibility for moving a database from Express to CE.

Answer (score 1):

Uh - if your application uses SQL Server ... then you need to make sure SQL Server is installed somewhere within network reach of your application.

Other alternatives to SQL Server include:

- [SQL Server embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- Embedded databases like [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (that's what Android uses, BTW)
- Read and write your own flat file or XML file as a local "data store"

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you are not permitted to distribute sql server 2008. You can however distribute sql express 2008. With express you can distribute the MSI and chain it during installation. You may also want to look at Compact Edition. You need to make a choice of which sql version works best for your needs